# call method from NSManagedObject from uiviewController (MVC pattern)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, model-view-controller, communication

My question is simple. How to communicate between my model and my controller ?

Code into controller

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Album" inManagedObjectContext:manageContext];
album = [[Album alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:manageContext];
NSArray *arrayListAlbums = [album returnAllAlbums];
```

Method into NSManagedObject

```
(NSArray *) returnAllAlbums
{

NSEntityDescription *entitydescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Album" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjContextAlbum];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entitydescription];

NSError *error;
NSArray *arrayListAlbums = [managedObjContextAlbum executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

return arrayListAlbums;
}
```

Comment: I have an error when i call returnAllAlbums since viewController

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided, you have added a convenience method in your `NSManagedObject` subclass and then you create an instance of the `NSManagedObject` to call that convenience method.  This is not a good design.

You are creating an empty data object to call a fetch method.  Perhaps you should have a class method "somewhere" that looks like this:

```
+ (NSArray *)returnAllAlbums:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
{
    NSEntityDescription *entitydescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Album" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entitydescription];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *arrayListAlbums = [managedObjContextAlbum executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (arrayListAlbums == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }

    return arrayListAlbums;
}
```

Which you can then access without creating an empty data object:

```
NSArray *arrayListAlbums = [MyClassWithFetchMethods returnAllAlbums:myLocalContextReference];
```